# Convert query to search in jsonb field from Postgres to Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I'm writing a project in Laravel 5.3, using Postgres 10 DB. My project includes a tags list, which are stored in a "tags" jsonb column (Value example: ["hello", "goodbye"]).

I'm looking to implement a filter by tags feature, which will include three different types of filters: any, all or none. (I'm given a list of tags, I have to filter columns which contain any of the tags, or all of them, etc). The following queries work fine in Postgres and are recommended by their documentation:

```
--any
select id, tags from product_listings
where tags::jsonb ?| array['sports', 'best seller'];

--all
select id, tags from product_listings
where tags::jsonb ?& array['sports', 'best seller']
```

However, I can't convert those queries to Laravel Eloquent. Those special jsonb operators aren't recognized by Laravel, and even writing the entire query using DB::raw failed. Specifically, the question mark seems to be the problem, and I can't get around it. I also couldn't find any equivalent clauses in Laravel's eloquent (there's WhereJsonContains, but it was introduced in Laravel 5.6 and it's impossible to upgrade now).

Is there any way to do it? Another idea was to discard the json aspect and simply treat the field as a string list, but even then we couldn't find any elegant solution to implement those filters.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `DB::raw()` the question mark are used to insert dynamic data in a safe way, e.g:

```php
DB::select('SELECT * FROM users where status = ?', ['confirmed']);
```

Will produce the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users where status = 'confirmed'
```

You could trick the system by binding your question mark... to another question mark

```
DB::select("select id, tags from product_listings where tags::jsonb ?| array['sports', 'best seller']", ['?']);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply and sorry for the delay! Sadly it's still not working. I'm able to use your tick to bind a question mark into a value (For example, tags = ?), but not for the actual operator. I still get the same error

  LINE 1: ... id, tags from product_listings where tags::jsonb $1| array[...  
With the dollar being marked. Seems like the question mark turns into $1 for some reason. Thanks!